# S3 Event Lambda Triggering Retention Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I see S3 Event can trigger Lambda, and I was wondering if I were to throttle at Lambda level, but at the S3 Put level, it is higher than the consumer.

How does the retention of these events work? Does Lambda HAVE to keep up with S3 Puts? Is there an internal streams or will events gets dropped?

Comment: You can read about [error handling and automatic retries in Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-retries.html) and [dead letter queues](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-lambda-supports-dead-letter-queues/).

Comment: @jamod Right, so say I dont configure those, but there is retries. But eventually I have all my lambdas are filled up. But new S3 events are still coming, even with async retries, it won't go pass the assigned concurrency would it?